# How do I sign my ios app under my App Store Connect Team, not myself?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer

So I just spent all weekend debugging and building an app for my client. I don't have my 100 dollar Apple Developer License anymore, so I can't upload it. I thought my signature would just be under my client's team automatically after they added me, but I guess not.

How can I sign the app as my client's team, so they have it, and I can upload to their dashboard?

I can't seem to be able to Google the right thing to find an answer.

Oh, and secondary question; could I just get the team license under my name to sign it, so I don't have to re-achieve it again? Not a huge deal if I have to wait again, but it would save me some time.

Edit: I did also directly ask Apple's support team, but I figured I would ask this here incase a fellow dev had an answer for me. I can't be the only freelancer who's had to build and push an app for a client. Cheers!

Comment: is your client account an individual Apple Developer account or an enterprise account?

Comment: You need that your client add you as a team member (choose a mail address different from yours)

Comment: Jabbar, he was able to add me as an admin, while he's an account holder. I think enterprise accounts are for 500+ organizations, right? This is just a few people. The email address I'm under is my Apple one I have published personal apps on before.